# How to change FeynArts Paint style settings?

Tags: plotting, color, style, plot-themes, feyncalc

I'm a Mathematica stylesheet enthusiast. I love using beautiful stylesheet instead of the default one, such as Dracular. I'm also a physics researcher on scattering amplitudes, which forces me to use FeynCalc and FeynArts etc. However, while all the other texts changes with my stylesheet, the diagrams `Paint` paints don't.

[image]
[image]

As you see, the paintings stay Black, which in such a dark background it's very hard to see.

I don't wanna give up my beautiful, coding-friendly stylesheet. How do I change the settings of FeynArts, or maybe `Paint` function, to let them suit my background?

Comment: Please code instead of images so that people can use your solution without retyping. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584).

Answer (score -1):

I ask and answer myself, because after seaching I found nobody asked this and I have to solve it myself. And very fortunately, I found the answer and it's quite easy!

First, I try to look at the options for `Paint` by `Options[Paint]`. No `Background` or `PlotStyle` -like stuffs are its options.

Then I try to dive into the whole blackbox——the FeynArts package's source files. In the very beginning, I copy the diagrams output and query about its Head, and I found it's Graphics (Actually all the `Plot`s and other graphs are with head "Graphics"). So I guess there should be `Graphics[...,options]` in the FeynArts source code. It is by changing Graphics' options that I can achieve my goal.

So I found the 《Graphics.m》 file in the FeynArts folder, which in my case is `C:\Users\19927\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\FeynCalc\FeynArts\FeynArts`. After testing, there are 2 and only 2 `Graphics[...]` in it and they indeed control the style of the outcome of `Paint`. They are as follows.

**The first one** is[image]. I add the 415th line of code, to set the painting color to be red. The effect is
[image], only changing the "PlotLabel".

**To see this, you need to quit and reload FeynArts.**

**The second one** is at around line 460.[image] I add the line 460 of code expecting to change sth to blue. The effect is[image].

So as you see, we find the keys. You can change to any style you want, or suitable for your stylesheet. **Btw, I think `Background -> White` is much better** since we always need to copy the Feynman diagrams to somewhere else.

Comment: Please, provide the code in a text form, not as a screenshot. Nobody wants to retype all of this :)